# Convert text based key/value pair to JSON format

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have a `text` file with a lot of key/value pairs in the given format:

```
secret_key="XXXXX"
database_password="1234"
timout=30
.
.
.
and list continues...
```

I want these key/value pairs to be stored in a `JSON` format so that I can make use of this data in the `JSON` format. Is there any way of doing this. I mean any website or any method to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 3.8 script below would do the job ◡̈

```
import json

with open('text', 'r') as fp:
    dic = {}
    while line:=fp.readline().strip():
        key, value = line.split('=')
        dic[key] = eval(value)
    print(json.dumps(dic))
```

Note: `eval` is used to prevent double quotes being escaped.

Answer (score 1):

As I guess that is an `.env` file. So, I would suggest you try to implement something like this in Python:

```
import json
import sys

try:
    dotenv = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError as e:
    dotenv = '.env'

with open(dotenv, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# removes whitespace chars like '\n' at the end of each line
content = [x.strip().split('=') for x in content if '=' in x]
print(json.dumps(dict(content)))
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/d6b2c2f7a69ebcd8430ea59c9bcc62c0

*Please let me know if you want to implement it in a different language, such as JavaScript.